# GROUP BY Not Calculating Correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have this statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS numberVote, AWARD_ID, NOMINEE_ID, VOTER_ID, MULTI_CODE 
FROM b_awards_vote 
WHERE AWARD_ID = 8 
GROUP BY MULTI_CODE
```

My table looks like this:

```
ID   |  AWARD_ID  | NOMINEE_ID  | VOTER_ID  | MUTLI_CODE
1    |  8         | 3           | 1         | 4837
2    |  8         | 4           | 1         | 4837
3    |  8         | 5           | 1         | 4837
```

However returning in php:

```
$numberVote = $row['numberVote'];
```

This statement returns 3.  Here is a little more detail into what I want:

1. All entries with the same MULTI_CODE are in fact 1 vote.
2. So this example in the table above I want to count as 1 vote.  In this table below:

   ```
   ID   |  AWARD_ID  | NOMINEE_ID  | VOTER_ID  | MUTLI_CODE
   1    |  8         | 3           | 1         | 4837
   2    |  8         | 4           | 1         | 4837
   3    |  8         | 5           | 1         | 4837
   4    |  8         | 4           | 3         | 7480
   5    |  8         | 5           | 3         | 7480
   ```
3. I would want this count to return: 2 as there are two different MULTI_CODE's as there are 2 different groups of votes.

Comment: Why did you use count(ID) and please provide the php code you used to display this data

Comment: Because you are doing group by using MULTI_CODE field only, while NOMINEE_ID field have distinct values.

Comment: not very clear what output you want or expect

Comment: It return 3 because you are grouping by  `MUTLI_CODE` and in your example you have 3 lines when same  `MUTLI_CODE`.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it a little.  I want to group the MULTI_CODE to class as 1 vote.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your example with more data and explain what is the desired outcome?

Comment: I have elaborated on what I mean in the question.

Comment: so do you want the number of distinct MULTI_CODE s ?

Comment: @andy i told you already, you have distincts fields like NOMINEE_ID. Sql wont be able to group them up and show them in one single row. Thats why you are getting 3 rows instead of 1.

Comment: Ok so it's not possible to count the number of different MULTI_CODEs based on what AWARD_ID there are?

Comment: I don't understand what part of this problem `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mutli_code [sic]) FROM my_table` fails to solve.

Comment: Just remove fields AWARD_ID, NOMINEE_ID, VOTER_ID, MULTI_CODE from your query and you will find the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will count the number of `MUTLI_CODE` groups you have:

```
  SELECT  COUNT( distinct MULTI_CODE) AS NumOfGroups ,ID AS numberVote, AWARD_ID, NOMINEE_ID, VOTER_ID, MULTI_CODE 
  FROM b_awards_vote 
  WHERE AWARD_ID = 8
```

see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b163/13) for reference

Comment: In general, if you have an unaggregated column in the SELECT, then that column should also appear in the GROUP BY. Equally, if you have an *aggregated* column in the SELECT then that column SHOULD NOT appear in the GROUP BY!